# How to implement a loading button in Ionic 4?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I want to insert into my Ionic 4 app the button, used in a form when, which once pressed show a ring/circle/spinner on the left during the waiting of the response from the server, during the operation. It is part of the Material Design, but I didn't found anything on the doc.
How Can I implement?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: The idea was integrating some css, but nothing works and I hope something already ready to be used!

Comment: This can be achieved using a boolean `loading` and `*ngIf` for the content of the button

Comment: Could you please answer with a fully working/simple example?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solution I suggested in the comments would look something like this:

```html
<ion-button (click)="doRequest()"> 
  <ion-label > <ion-spinner *ngIf="loading"></ion-spinner> Submit</ion-label>
</ion-button>
```

```js
export class Component {
  loading: boolean;

  doRequest() {
    this.loading = true;
    this.service.makeRequest().subscribe(
      res => { 
        this.loading = false;
        // Do something else...
      }
    ); 
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Changed to `ion-spinner` as @JanP suggested in comments

Comment: A spinning loader with animation is implemented out of the box in Ionic with `<ion-spinner></ion-spinner>`